# Problemas con consulta where por medio de select

Tags: laravel-5

Buen dia

He tratado de realizar una consulta filtrada, es decir, en mi vista selecciono un nombre, luego de seleccionado le doy buscar y deberia aparecer todos los registros relacionados con ese nombre.

en mi vista tengo esto:

https://paste.laravel.io/b5b2bb65-7b2d-43b0-8cbd-5002d36bb4ff

En mi controlador tengo esto:

https://paste.laravel.io/89aa0476-cc6d-4ebe-b53f-29894680e79a

No logro enviar el dato que quiero al controlador

Answer (score 0, accepted):

en tu vista

```
 <form action="{{action('UsuarioController@show')}}" method="post">
                {{csrf_field()}}
                   <select name="tipo" id="tipo" class=" form-control"  value="{{ old('tipo') }}"  required>
                    @foreach($usuarios as  $usuario)
                      <option value="{{$usuario->usuario_ad }}">{{ $usuario->nombre }}</option>
                   @endforeach
               </select>
            <a class="btn btn-info" >Buscar</a>
         </form>
```

en tu controlador

```
$usuarios=usuarios::where("usuario_ad","=",$request->tipo)->get();
return  view('usuario.index',compact('usuarios'));
```

espero te sirva o te ayude un poco en tu logica

Comment: Gracias reyesg, me ha servido mucho

Comment: @zereft de nada bro

Answer (score 0):

Buenas pruebas con esto, ya que estas lanzando una ruta POST necesitas acceder a la variable request.

```
<form action="{{action('UsuarioController@show')}}" method="post">
  {{csrf_field()}}
  <select name="tipo" id="tipo" class=" form-control"  value="{{ old('tipo') }}"  required>
         @foreach($usuariosOpciones as $id => $usuario_ad)
         <option value="{{ $id }}">{{ $usuario_ad }}</option>
         @endforeach
  </select>
  <a class="btn btn-info" >Buscar</a>
 </form>
```

Para acceder al valor del select, el select tiene que estar dentro de las etiquetas del "form".

```
public function show(Request $request)
        {
            $usuarios=usuarios::where("usuario_ad","=",$request->usuario_ad)->get();
            $tipo = $request->tipo; //Para acceder a la variable del select
            return  view('usuario.index',compact('usuarios'));
        }
```

Comment: Tienes razon, tenia dudas sobre como recibir datos en este metodo, sin embargo no logro conseguir que el formulario envie dicha variable, como puedo hacer para que lo que tenga en el select en ese momento lo pueda enviar por post?              https://paste.laravel.io/e9bdcbb0-369b-4ef2-9207-2472f52f7236

Comment: @zereft te he actualizado la respuesta.

Comment: Muy bien.. hice los cambios, pero ahora aparece este error,   "Undefined variable: usuario_ad (View: C:\laragon\www\crudgobernaciontres\resources\views\Usuario\index.blade.php)    me señala la primera linea del formulario    <form action="<?php echo e(action('UsuarioController@show', $usuario_ad)); ?>" method="post">

Comment: tal vez si ves mis archivos completos, puedas entender mejor, mira   view complet: https://paste.laravel.io/ed0d4013-d4e0-4a4e-b342-0915ff953bc5

controller complet: https://paste.laravel.io/ae53372b-efca-4a7d-9a18-d15edb69dc3d

Comment: @zereft quita de la ruta show el parametro. Y trabaja en el controlador lo que necesites del usuario ya q tienes el id del usuario en el valor del select.